# Operate inside a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list

I created a list with

```
list.files(pattern="*.csv")
file_list <- lapply(list_of_files, read_csv, col_names = TRUE)
```

Do you know can I apply the same function to all the files in the list?  I tried with `function(df)` but it doesn't work. I need to:

- Rename all the columns inside the data frames in the same way
- Concatenate column A and B, and C and D inside of each data frames.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `file_list_changed <- lapply(file_list, your_function)`. Oh, in "apply the same function to all the files in the list", they are no longer *files*, they are data.frames.

Comment: You can do it all inside the initial `lapply()`, or use another `lapply()` to manipulate each data.frame in your `file_list`

Comment: ``file_list <- lapply(list_of_files, function(x) read_csv(x col_names = TRUE))``

Comment: To rename columns, I tried this and didn't work: names_cols<-c("a", "b", "c", "d","e")
new_columns<-lapply(file_list, colnames(file_list, names_cols))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lapply(list_of_files, read_csv, col_names = TRUE)` runs functions read_csv(file=list_of_files[[1]], colnames=TRUE), read_csv(file=list_of_files[[2]], colnames=TRUE) etc. and returns output from each run as a slot of a list.

It can run any function. You can either define your own function like

```
my_data_trans<-function(fn){
df<- read_csv(fn, colnames=TRUE)
colnames(df)<- c("Number", "Charge", "Potential_Ch", "Discharge","Potential_Disch")) 
dfcon <- rbind(df[,c(1, 2,3)], df[,c(1, 4, 5)])
colnames(df)<-c("Number", "Charge+Discharge", "Potential_Ch+Potential_Disch")) 
# any other transformation
return(dfcon)
}
lapply(list_of_files, my_data_trans)
```

Or you can use anonymous function = skip name and put only function definition

```
lapply(list_of_files, function(fn) {
#same as above
})
```

Comment: Thank you Ivana. With concatenation, I mean that I have column 1,2,3,4,5. I need to put together columns 2 and 4, and 3 and 5. The result will be a new data frame with 3 columns: column 1, column 2 (sum of 2+4), and column 3( sum of 3+5).

Comment: I have edited my answer. I took column names from your comments above. I believe you actually want to stack (merge, combine) charge and discharge as one column as the two potentials as another. Is this right? Sum I see as aritmetical operation (e.g. 76+5=81)

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I am getting an error on colnames(df), though. I am using colnames(*name of the list*)<-c(...). Is it wrong?

Comment: list does not have colnames. A matrix or data.frame has.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

file_list <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {
  setNames(x, c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>%
    mutate(AB = paste0(A, B), CD = paste0(C, D)) %>%
    return()
})
```

Comment: Thanks. How does the mutate function work here? If my columns have new names and are ordered numerically by R?

Comment: What do mean by columns being ordered numerically by R?

Comment: Update. This code actually works file_list2 <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {
  setNames(x, c("Number", "Charge", "Potential_Ch", "Discharge","Potential_Disch")) %>%
    mutate(paste0(2, 4),paste0(3, 5)) %>%
    return()
}).    But it gives me a new list with the names I wanted, and two new columns with 24 and 35. I need to put column 4 under column 2, and column 5 under column 3. So the new data frames will have 3 columns (1, 2+4, and 3+5). I am sorry if I am not explaining this clearly.

Comment: `file_list2 <- lapply(file_list, function(x) { setNames(x, c("Number", "Charge", "Potential_Ch", "Discharge","Potential_Disch")) %>% {rbind(.[, 1:3], select(., Number, Charge = Discharge, Potential_Ch = Potential_Disch))} %>% return() })`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of just doing all in the original lapply, as I mentioned in the comments

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

lapply(list_of_files, \(f) {
  read_csv(f, col_names=TRUE) %>% 
    rename_with(~c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>%  
    mutate(newcol1 = paste0(A,B),newcol2 = paste0(C,D))
})
```